# Data.frame vs Data.table in R?

Tags: data-mining, r, data-cleaning

Data.table package is claimed to be faster than Data.frame. what are the implementation changes that made this possible? How can one leverage the power of this package for data analysis?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21435339/2114932

Answer (score 3):

You have a nice free course about it on DataCamp

> [Data Analysis in R, the data.table Way](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-table-data-manipulation-r-tutorial)

The author of the course is Matt Dowle, the guy that actually wrote the data.table package.

Hope that helps.